# How to use my PyCharm Python Interpreter in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, interpreter, anaconda3

Is it possible to use the Python interpreter that I have been using in PyCharm in Jupyter Notebook? I'm not looking to create a brand new virtual environment as I have tried that and encountered "Solving Environment" issues when trying to install packages. How do I get Jupyter Notebook to use my current interpreter `~/opt/anaconda3/envs/PopulationDensity/bin/python` as the interpreter?

I have also tried `python -m ipykernel install --user --name <kernel_name> --display-name "<Name_to_display>"` as suggested in another thread and substituted `<kernel_name>` with my interpreter path, but that resulted in a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to install Jupyter notebook in the interpreter that Pycharm happens to use and invoke Jupyter notebook from there.

As Pycharm creates new virtual environments for your projects(by default settings), you need to first activate that interpreter.

The Jupyter notebook invoked like above has access to all packages that Pycharm has access to.

Open up a terminal, active the venv and then:

```bash
pip install notebook
```

```bash
jupyter notebook
```

In every running Python you can check the interpreter path with:

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: Ok, I've gotten as far as opening my project in the Jupyter Notebook through PyCharm, but this notebook appears to lack the functionality of my other Jupyter notebooks, as in I can't run cells. Is this because it did not open as ipykernel? When creating a new notebook, the only option is to use Python 3 (ipykernel) and not my PyCharm environment.

Comment: @Exquisite_Poupon A venv is somewhere in your hard drive, it has it's own isolated environment with packages installed. Pycharm, VScode, etc can activate and use that environment. That means you don't need to have Pycharm opened in order to run Jupyter notebook. Just open your terminal, activate that environment and run `jupyter notebook`. This should open up a Jupyter notebook which can do anything(run cells, etc) *and* have access to the same virtual environment that Pycharm happens to use.

Comment: I should also state that trying to import packages in newly created notebooks results in a ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: @Exquisite_Poupon Check the updated answer. Does it solve your problem now?

Comment: @ S.B The environment I want to use was created through Pycharm's Preferences>Python Interpreter window using a conda environment. If I have the file pathname of that interpreter, can I use that to activate that environment? I've tried activating that environment in Terminal using `source ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/PopulationDensity/bin/python/activate` but it returns that that is not a directory.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, so this is for anyone who is also having trouble with this in the future. I had to add activate the environment in Terminal using `source activate PopulationDensity` and then register the environment with IPython so Jupyter Notebook can use it as an option. I did this with `ipython kernel install --name PopulationDensity --user`. Then start up Jupyter Notebook and you should be able to choose your new environment! I used [this website](https://sites.northwestern.edu/researchcomputing/resources/adding-python-3-to-jupyter-notebook/) as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

I use `pipenv` to create venvs and here is how it worked for me:

1. On the terminal with activated venv, do:

`(my_venv) me@my_pc:~/my_project$ python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=my_venv`

2. It creates a kernel.json file:

`/home/me/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/my_venv/kernel.json`

3. In the json file, check if the correct python interpreter is selected:

`"/home/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_venv/bin/python3.9"`

4. In your notebook file inside PyCharm, on the upper bar, you should see 2 kernels: `Python 3 (ipykernel)` and `my_venv` select the newly-created `my_venv`

Within the notebook you can check if you use the correct interpreter:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Previously it was showing `'/usr/bin/python3'`. Now it is same as what I set in the json file.